# FormRewriterControlAdapter and VS2010

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, iis-6

I am using `FormRewriterControlAdapter` in VS2010 (.NET 3.5).

When I compile and deploy, form tag have wrong action attribute. I need to delete `__browserCapabilitiesCompiler.compiled` to work. But I don't know if have any collateral effect.

Why?

I found one case similar: http://quangouk.spaces.live.com/blog/cns!AC44601E5195662B!246.entry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use FormRewriterControlAdapter, and I do not have __browserCapabilitiesCompiler.compiled on Bin and its working fine the last 2 years :) and still working after I have update to VS2010.

So delete it.

Comment: But why compiler generate this file? If VS2010 works just without the file, then have some consequences deleting it.